Time to burninate the [beginner] tag? (+[intermediate] and [advanced] tags)
The beginner tag (with 28 Q's) is one of those meta tags which are generally discouraged; see: The Death of Meta Tags.  If the question is well-formed this tag shouldn't be needed.
I plan to burninate it (i.e., edit it out of the questions that contain it).  Along the way, I'll likely make other edits.
I thought I should mention this in case there's anything else that needs saying.

I just noticed, I can't completely get rid myself of it because one question is locked: How to practice reading for beginners?

I've noticed there's also intermediate and advanced which should be burninated for the same reason.  At this point there's 3 questions left:

What is important to consider while building an adverbial phrase?

What are some well-known, online news sources that are worthy of language study?

Where to start/continue my learning?


which would be nice to close before retagging (but haven't quite got there yet).

Still one more to go

beginner intermediate advanced are now burninated.  Obligatory image:

There's still that one [beginner] question left which is "locked" and I can't edit.  I can't even flag it.  That tag's gone now, so the beginner tag has been burninated.  Likewise advanced has been burninated.
One question still has the intermediate tag: Where to start/continue my learning?  It needs just one more close vote: in my opinion, it's very much an "advice" question.  I diamond-hammer closed this one: it was on 4 close votes (although one was pre-diamond mine).  I'm confident vague "what should I do?" study-advice questions are off-topic for both "Needs more focus" (what's your specific question?) and "Opinion-based".  (At Islam.SE, we had similar questions "I'm a Muslim with a problem; what should I do?";  this is the equivalent "I'm a Chinese student with a problem; what should I do?")
Anyway, it's done.
